# Fastest way to process http request

Tags: c++, http, esp32, platformio

I am currently working on creating a network of multisensors (measuring temp, humidity ect). There will be tens or in some buildings even hundreds of sensors measuring at the same time. All these sensors send their data via a http GET request to a local esp32 server that processes the data and converts it into whatever the building's contol system can work with (KNX, BACnet, MODbus). Now I stress tested this server and found out that it can process around 1400 requests per minute before the sender gets no response anymore. This seems like a high amount but if a sensor sends its data every 2 seconds it means there will be a limit of around 45 sensors. I need to find a way how to process such a request quicker, this is the code I currently use:

```
server.on("/get-data", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
         {handle_get_data(request); request->send(200); });

void handle_get_data(AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{
  packetval++;
  sensorData.humidity = request->arg("humidity").toFloat();
  sensorData.temperature = request->arg("temperature").toFloat();
  sensorData.isMovement = request->arg("isMovement");
  sensorData.isSound = request->arg("isSound");
  sensorData.luxValue = request->arg("luxValue").toDouble();
  sensorData.RSSI = request->arg("signalValue").toInt();
  sensorData.deviceID = request->arg("deviceID");
  sensorData.btList = request->arg("btList");
  if (deviceList.indexOf(sensorData.deviceID) == -1)
  {
    deviceList += sensorData.deviceID;
    activeSensors++;
  }
  if (sensorData.isMovement || sensorData.isSound)
  {
    sendDataFlag = true;
  }
}
```

I use the AsyncTCP library.
Now I measured the execution time of the function `handle_get_data()` and it turns out it is only ~175uS which is very quick. However the time between two calls of `handle_get_data()` is around 6ms which is really slow but it still doesnt explain why I can only process 1400 per minute or 24 per second (6ms = 155Hz why is my limit 24Hz?). Other than that I do not use any other code during the processing of a request, is it perhaps a limitation in the library? Is there another way to process such a request?
A request looks like this: `http://192.168.6.51:80/get-data?humidity=32.0&temperature=32.0&isMovement=1&isSound=1&luxValue=123&RSSI=32&deviceID=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX&btList=d1d2d3d4d5d6d7`
If there is really nothing I can do I can always switch to a raspberry pi to process everything but I would rather stick to esp32 since I want to easily create an own PCB.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: why do you use HTTP?

Comment: I dont need to use HTTP, if there is another way to transfer data over network faster I'd love to hear it!

Comment: 24 requests per second seems reasonably quick for a microcontroller? do your sensors maintain tcp connections between requests? HTTP is quite heavyweight other protocols are lighter, you could use MQTT for example (though I'm not sure of the performance from having the broker on a microcontroller)

Comment: Did your server drop the connection after sending response or keep alive when you measure the 6ms turn around? What if using websocket, and without http?

Comment: To be honest, temperature and humidity do not change much with every 2s, especially in building automation application (and your BACnet might be even slower) and many of your data can be sent as events (i.e. only when it is changed), even you can shorten the turn around time, you have not consider time taken to store the data into database yet and the size of your storage required to store huge data received...

Comment: Im currently experimenting with websockets thanks to @hcheung. When I finalise it I will post the code but currently it looks very promising; I am able to process around 6000+ packets per minute which is around 100kb/s so I think Im not gonna be able to squize much more out of the esp.

Comment: @hcheung's observation is really important. Where does the requirement for reporting every 2 seconds come from? Why does that make sense?

Comment: @romkey, OP mentioned that near the end of first paragraph.

Comment: fastest way is to send binary data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a websocket instead of using http requests solved the issue for me:

```
AsyncWebSocket ws("/ws");

void setup()
{
  ws.onEvent(onWsEvent);
  server.addHandler(&ws);
}

AsyncWebSocketClient *wsClient;
void onWsEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type, void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
  if (type == WS_EVT_DATA)
  {
    AwsFrameInfo *info = (AwsFrameInfo *)arg;
    String msg = "";
    packetval++;
    if (info->final && info->index == 0 && info->len == len)
    {
      if (info->opcode == WS_TEXT)
      {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < info->len; i++)
        {
          msg += (char)data[i];
        }
      }
    }
    sensorData.humidity = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<hum>") + 5, msg.indexOf("</hum>")).toFloat();
    sensorData.temperature = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<tem>") + 5, msg.indexOf("</tem>")).toFloat();
    sensorData.isMovement = (msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<isMov>") + 7, msg.indexOf("</isMov>")) == "1");
    sensorData.isSound = (msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<isSnd>") + 7, msg.indexOf("</isSnd>")) == "1");
    sensorData.luxValue = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<lux>") + 5, msg.indexOf("</lux>")).toDouble();
    sensorData.RSSI = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<RSSI>") + 6, msg.indexOf("</RSSI>")).toInt();
    sensorData.deviceID = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<dID>") + 5, msg.indexOf("</dID>"));
    sensorData.btList = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("<bt>") + 4, msg.indexOf("</bt>"));
    if (deviceList.indexOf(sensorData.deviceID) == -1)
    {
      deviceList += sensorData.deviceID;
      activeSensors++;
    }
    if (sensorData.isMovement || sensorData.isSound)
    {
      sendDataFlag = true;
    }
  }
}
```

This will process more than 11000 packets per minute (200kb/s). The execution time of `void onWsEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type, void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len)` takes ~500uS now which means there is definitly optimising to do in this function but the time between two calls is reduced all the way to 1ms.

Comment: but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Juraj well it doesnt answer the question on how to handle a http request quicker but it did solve the issue for me. It wasnt necesarry for me to use http that why I also asked if there is another way to solve this problem.